# Find the natural number solution to the equation $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{y}+\frac{3}{z}=1$

Tags: number-theory

What I can do is, $x\gt 1, y \gt 2$ and $z \gt 3$. One of the solution I found is $x=3, y=6, z=9$. Is it the only solution?

Comment: $(2,6,18)$ is another solution.

Comment: The same problem on AoPS (but it is not fully solved in either thread it seems!): https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1069822p4647803 and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1068820h2123669p15467480

Comment: Suppose that $y = ax, z = bx$.
Then the LHS goes to $(1/x)[1 + 2/a + 3/b] = 1 \implies
1 + 2/a + 3/b = x.$
Suppose, for example that you set $a = 4$.
Then, you will have to have $3/b$ be expressible as $n + (1/2)$.
You could take $b = 2$.
This means that $x = 1 + (1/2) + (3/2) = 3.$
Then, $y = 12$ and $z = 6$.

Comment: @nmasanta It is a slightly different question though 

Comment: I found that there are $32$ solutions. The smallest for $\,x\,$ is $\,x=2, y=5, z=30.\,$ The largest is $\,x=36, y=9, z=4.\,$ The largest value for $\,x,y,z\,$ is $\,y=40.\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exactly 32 solutions to the equation $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{y}+\frac{3}{z}=1;x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$$The solutions in the form of $(x,y,z)$ are: $(2,5,30),(2,6,18),(2,7,14),(2,8,12),(2,10,10),(2,12,9),(2,16,8),(2,28,7),(3,4,18),(3,6,9),(3,12,6),(3,30,5),(4,3,12),(4,4,12),(4,8,6),(5,4,10),(5,40,4),(5,10,5),(6,3,18),(6,4,9),(6,6,6),(6,24,4),(8,4,8),(8,16,4),(10,5,6),(12,3,12),(12,12,4),(14,4,7),(15,6,5),(20,10,4),(30,3,10),(39,9,4)$

To get these solutions, I checked every natural number pair of $(x,y)$ up to $(400,400)$. We only need the two variables because we can solve for the last one. Solving for $z$, we get $$z=\frac{3xy}{xy-y-2x}$$ We know that $z$ is a natural number, so this is essentially asking the same thing as "When is $z=\frac{3xy}{xy-y-2x}$ a natural number?"

Either those are the only solutions, or the next solution just has really big numbers. To prove the former case, we know that if there is another solution, then either $x$ or $y$ must be greater than $39$ and $40$ respectively since those are the largest values for $x$ and $y$ in the set I've provided.

We'll start with your original problem and manipulate it to get this: $$\frac{2}{y}+\frac{3}{z}=1-\frac{1}{x}$$Since $x\gt39$,$$1-\frac{1}{x}\gt\frac{38}{39}\Rightarrow\frac{2}{y}+\frac{3}{z}\gt\frac{38}{39}$$So, now we know that if there is a solution to your original problem with $x\gt39$, then that second inequality must also be true. There are fourteen integer pairs that fit that description if $y\gt2$ and $z\gt3$ (you can graph this on Desmos to see). Checking all of them, we see that none of them are solutions to your original problem. That must mean that our assumption of $x\gt39$ was false.

This also works if you replace $y$ instead of $x$ which gets you $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{3}{z}\gt\frac{39}{40}$$resulting in five possible integer pairs given $x\gt1$ and $z\gt3$. Again, we find that none of them are solutions to your problem. We started by assuming that if there is another solution, then either $x\gt39$ or $y\gt40$. We proved that neither of those cases are true. So that means there are no other solutions.